# Grammatical analisys doubt

Tags: грамматика

I have a doubt regarding Russian grammatical analysis. 
“Вы спрашиваете, что я делаю». 
Что, is it a наречие или местоимение? And Why? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

> Вы спрашиваете, что я делаю.

**Что** can be either **союз** or **союзное слово (местоимение)**.It cannot be наречие. There are only two more words, that can be either союз or союзное слово (наречие ). They are **как** and **когда**.

There are several ways to distinguish between союз and союзное слово.
1.Союзное слово is always **stressed**. Like in your sentence. Compare:

> Он сказал,что (он) любит конфеты.(что is not stressed,it's союз)
>
> Он спросил,что я делаю.(что is stressed, it's союзное слово)

2.Besides you can **leave out** союз without changing sense

> Он сказал, (он) любит конфеты.

But you cannot leave out союзное слово.

There are some more ways concerning the **function** of the word in the sentence or the possibility to **change** союзное слово.

So in your sentence it's **союзное слово (местоимение)**

3.Function.

> Он спросил, что я делаю.(я is a subject, делаю is a verb,что is an object)

In the sentence Он сказал, что (он) любит конфеты.что has no other function than connecting the main and the subordinate clauses.

Comment: probably also **когда** and **который** (to a lesser extent **кто**)

Comment: у вас ошибка в 3. я -подлежащие, делаю - сказуемое, а вот что будет союзным словом, местоимение(подразумеваю, что я что-то делаю)

Answer (score 1):

**Союз или союзное слово** (местоимение, наречие)?

Эта задача решается при анализе сложных предложений, передающих дословную речь (свою или чужую), например:

*Он спросил, **что** я делаю* (ЧТО – союзное слово, местоимение). *Я ответил, **что** читаю книгу* (ЧТО – союз, служебное слово).

1) **Если в предложении есть вопросительные слова** (местоимения ***что, кто*** или наречия ***когда, где, как***), то  они выполняют двойную работу:  являются  вопросительными местоимениями или наречиями и одновременно средствами связи (союзными словами): *Он спросил, чтО я делаю.* (На союзное слово падает ударение).

2) **Если вопросительных слов нет**, то для связи простых предложений используются союзы: *Я ответил, **что** читаю книгу.* (На союз не падает ударение, он не является членом предложения).

**Ответ на вопрос:**

Вы спрашиваете, ***что*** я делаю? В предложении есть вопросительное слово ЧТО, это **местоимение** в роли союзного слова.

Он спросил, ***когда*** я приеду. В предложении есть вопросительное слово КОГДА, это **наречие** в роли союзного слова.